# Development banner missing

Tags: jhipster

I am not exactly sure what is going on but once I have done a "mvn -Pprod package" I am no longer able to run in development mode with the "development" banner showing and the "API" option in the "Administration" menu.
This is not a major as I can still get to the "#/docs" page by editing the browser url. It is just confusing for by development team.
I've had a quick look at the javascript stuff, but it scares me (I'm just a C programmer normally). Does anyone know how easily reset something in the javascript front end code so the "inProduction" flag work properly.
Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Updated for JHipster 7+

This is the expected behavior, the development ribbon is only displayed when run in dev profile, same thing for API docs for security reasons. There are other behaviors that are based on the profile like caching, etc ...

The war file that you built with `mvnw -Pprod package` can also be executed with dev profile set on command line.

If this is not enough for you, you can edit `src/main/resources/config/application.yml`
and set `display-ribbon-on-profiles: "dev,prod"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I created new jhipster project, ranit up in STS before packaging it in prod mode and then  dev mode and using "git diff" to show me the changes. I discovered that running the "mvn -Pprod package" changed a line in src/main/webapp/scripts/app/app.constact.js to be '.constant("ENV", "prod")' but running "mvn -Pdev package" does not change it back automatically.